# How to create checkToken in SpringBoot microservice?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, microservices

I'm creating a microservice framework in spring boot 3 and spring security 6, and I'm not understanding how I can make my client application validate the token in the authenticating application.

```
@Bean
@SneakyThrows
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

    return http.build();
}

@Primary
@Bean
public RemoteTokenServices tokenServices() {
    final var tokenService = new RemoteTokenServices();
    tokenService.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(authUrl + "/oauth/check_token");
    tokenService.setClientId(oauthClient);
    tokenService.setClientSecret(oauthClientSecret);
    tokenService.setAccessTokenConverter(new JwtAccessTokenConverterCustom());

    return tokenService;
}
```

I tried to run it the same way I did with previous versions, but I got no results.